# How do I connect to the internet through client's wifi? | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, serversocket, python-sockets

I've set up my server.py and client.py with the socket module, is there a way you can connect to the internet through the client? What i mean is, I want to have the server connect to the client through it's own internet, and then from there have the client use its internet to browse the web. But I have no idea how to do this.

So is there something I can leverage to achiece this?

Server:

```
import socket, threading
from time import sleep

PORT = 5430
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f'[NEW CONNECTIONS] {addr} connected')

    while True:
         conn.recv(6000)
    conn.close()

def start(): 
    server.listen()
    print(f'[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}')
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()

        thread = threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args = (conn,addr))
        thread.start()

        print(f'[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}')

print('[STARTNG] Server is starting')
start()
```

Client:

```
from time import sleep
import socket

PORT = 5430
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) 
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

while True:
     client.send('hi').encode(FORMAT)

conn.close()
```

Comment: You set this up in the operating system network coniguration, not in Python.

Comment: It sounds like your asking "How do I set up a proxy in Python?"  It's possible, https://pypi.org/project/proxy.py - but make sure you're authorized to do so on both devices, otherwise you run into legalities.